# Global state object in C#/WinRT

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-runtime, reactive-programming

For simplicity's sake, I'm trying to implement the following architecture in C# / XAML / WinRT:

```
Global App State -> Bindings -> Pages / User Controls etc -|
        ^                                                  |
        |------------- update -----------------------------|
```

So basically, FP/reactive-stylish. Pages and UI are bound to the properties of a global state object, and whenever a view wants to update something, it changes the global app state directly (or through a view model class, whatever), updating all other dependant parts of the app instantly (through the bindings).

I know about `DependencyProperties` and `INotifyPropertyChanged`, so binding to properties shouldn't be a problem.

However, ideally, I would like this to happen *even if I replace the global state object entirely*. Let's say, it's a multi-user app, then I would like to switch users like this:

```
App.State = LoadStateForUser(...);
```

and all part of the UI bound to the global state update. Right now I would have to set every different attribute myself. Is this possible somehow?

Note, I'm not asking advice on MVC or MVVM or whatever else design patters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this, but it certainly won't be automatic.

I would have an event on `App` (or a `GloablStateService`, or whatever) that indicated the global state had changed (`GlobalStateChanged` seems reasonable).

Your view models would then subscribe to this event and when it was raised by the setter you showed above, raise the correct `PropertyChanged` events so the UI updates. If your viewmodel's primary bound property was a simple reference to the global state object, this should be just one event raise.